# How to start new activity without killing current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, whatsapp

I have 2 activities (audio chat activity & message chat activity). Currently both activities working absolutely fine but now I want to both activity should work simultaneously like a Whatsapp messenger.

In audio chat activity there is a button to go into message chat activity but once message chat activity starts the audio chat activity stop working.

Is there any way where I can switch between these two activities like a Whatsapp messenger.

Comment: Do you have a code sniplet showing what are you doing? That would help. I'm guessing you are calling `finish()` somewhere ?

Comment: Your solution would be to put one of them into a separate process like a Service. So like your activity is handling the audio chat, but then you are receiving text updates from the service which your activity then updates on the screen. If you want the audio chat to continue while navigating to different parts of the app, that would require a separate service as well.

Comment: Question is misleading, please, rephrase what you want, in more specific details. You are NOT killing current activity, just following the lifecycle (and thus, `A.onPause().`, `B.onCreate()`, `B.onResume()`.... if you need, `A` is still there.

Comment: I think you should try with fragments inside your main activity

Answer (score 1):

You should change approach. When you start a new Activity B, Activity A is paused, so it can't work. For your purpose you should use a single Activity and show/hide elements (e.g.: messagebox and audiobox)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee that an activity that sits below another activity will never get killed.  Android can do this to reclaim memory when needed.  It's the way Android was designed to facilitate devices with limited resources.

Instead, if you want to let the user seamlessly switch between text and audio chat, you will need to maintain the UI between those two components in the same activity.  The easiest way is to simply have two different sets of views in the view hierarchy for the activity and switch between them by changing their visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helpful to developer,may be fresher or senior,I have ActivityA and B,this is my ActivityB class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intnt=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityA.class);
     startActivity(intnt);

}
```

please use this step in ActivityB to move back your AcitivityA without killed

And solution is

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

//I hide these below intent(2lines) in ActivityB,So it works thanks by Daemon....